# Unable to send mail outside network via PostFix

Tags: centos, postfix

I need assistance with an error I'm getting via postfix on CentOS.

I'm receiving the following error when trying to send a test email from a server in our DMZ to any email address outside our internal network:

```
Feb 24 13:55:09 media postfix/smtpd[8926]: 2F06E3202D0: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]

Feb 24 13:55:14 media postfix/cleanup[8929]: 2F06E3202D0: message-id=

Feb 24 13:55:14 media postfix/qmgr[8745]: 2F06E3202D0: from=, size=375, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Feb 24 13:55:14 media postfix/smtp[8930]: 2F06E3202D0: lost connection with gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.93.26] while receiving the initial server greeting

Feb 24 13:55:14 media postfix/smtp[8930]: 2F06E3202D0: lost connection with alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.229.26] while receiving the initial server greeting

Feb 24 13:55:14 media postfix/smtp[8930]: 2F06E3202D0: lost connection with alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.79.26] while receiving the initial server greeting

Feb 24 13:55:14 media postfix/smtp[8930]: 2F06E3202D0: lost connection with alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.69.26] while receiving the initial server greeting

Feb 24 13:55:14 media postfix/smtp[8930]: 2F06E3202D0: to=, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.173.27]:25, delay=10, delays=10/0/0.02/0, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.173.27] while receiving the initial server greeting)
```

This is my first time working with postfix so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The server has an SPF setup for it and the domain is not blacklisted.

Comment: Can you please post your postfix configuration?
main.cf and master.cf would be useful, more important the main.cf file from /etc/postfix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like a network issue rather than a postfix issue. Have you tried connecting to the remote server using `telnet 74.125.93.26 25`, and then [sending a message from the telnet session?](http://www.wikihow.com/Send-Email-Using-Telnet)

Comment: This doesn't really provide an answer to what the true problem was with the firewall. However, it was a firewall issue so I'll award you the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you resolved it.